# Can you edit nonces for MultiSend transactions on Gnosis UI?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is there a way to edit the safe nonce of a multisend transaction thats been proposed to the safe transaction api? Or maybe I can recreate the transaction with the intended nonce? It'd be useful if I can dynamically order my transactions after the fact, rather than during the time of creation.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions that are proposed to the service can be signed by the owners. Allowing to edit this transactions would make the process more chaotic requiring the owners to sign again.

It is not allowed to edit proposed transactions, but new ones can be proposed with the same nonce if desired.

The Web UI allows to edit the nonce before creating a new transaction in the "Advanced options" section.